# one table property have relation with two table properties .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a table named **News** and I want to store images with high and low quality and their information for each new, so I've created another table named **NewsAttachment** and this table should have relation with **News** but I already have another table named **NewsComment** that have relation with **News** too and when I want to define both as foreign key, SQL Server add another column in **News** and **NewsAttachment**.

---

This is **News** class:

```
public class News
{
    [Key]
    public int NewsId { get; set; } //primary key
    .
    .
    .
    //navigation property
    public virtual List<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual List<NewsAttachments> Comments { get; set; }
    public News()
    {

    }
}
```

---

This is **Comment** class:

```
public class Comments
{
    [Key]
    public int CommentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int NewsId { get; set; }  //Foreign key of News
    .
    .
    .
    //navigation property
    public virtual News News { get; set; }
    public Comments()
    {

    }
}
```

---

This is **NewsAttachment** class:

```
public class NewsAttachment
{
    [Key]
    public int NewsAttachmentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int NewsId { get; set; }  //Foreign key of News


    //Image information property
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string RealFileName { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string FilePageType { get; set; }

    //navigation property
    public News News { get; set; }
    public NewsAttachment()
    {

    }
}
```

---

**Summery of my question:**
I want to NewsId in **News** have relation with two other properties in tables but it run in to trouble.

If it's not possible to solve this problem please give me another way to save my two photos and their information in my database.

Comment: I don't see any problem if any news have several unicue attachments. If the same attachments can be for different news?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare it specifically to EF so it know which is the foreign key:

```
public class NewsAttachment
{
    [Key]
    public int NewsAttachmentId { get; set; }

    public int NewsId { get; set; }  //Foreign key of News    

    //Image information property
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string RealFileName { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string FilePageType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("NewsId")]
    public News News { get; set; }
    public NewsAttachment()
    {

    }
}
```